# Dynamically identifying properties in C#

Tags: c#, properties

Is there a way to dynamically identify design time properties in C#?  For example:

```
class MyClass
{
    public string MyProperty1 { get; set; }  
}
```

And then reference it something like this:

```
string myVar = "MyProperty1";
MyClass.myVar = "test";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to set the value of a property at runtime and the name of the property is only known at runtime you need to use [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx). Here's an example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string MyProperty1 { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // You need an instance of a class 
        // before being able to set property values            
        var myClass = new MyClass();
        string propertyName = "MyProperty1";
        // obtain the corresponding property info given a property name
        var propertyInfo = myClass.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);

        // Before trying to set the value ensure that a property with the
        // given name exists by checking for null
        if (propertyInfo != null)
        {
            propertyInfo.SetValue(myClass, "test", null);

            // At this point you've set the value of the MyProperty1 to test 
            // on the myClass instance
            Console.WriteLine(myClass.MyProperty1);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for highlighting the Properties and Fields need to be accessed differently.

Answer (score 1):

how about simply implementing an indexer on your class

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string MyProperty1 { get; set; }

    public object this[string propName]
    {
        get
        {
            return GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(this, null);
        }
        set
        {
            GetType().GetProperty(propName).SetValue(this, value, null);
        }
    }
}
```

and then you can do something very similar

```
var myClass = new MyClass();
string myVar = "MyProperty1";
myClass[myVar] = "test";
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course you can.  You need to get a `FieldInfo` object relating to the property that you want to set.

```
var field = typeof(MyClass).GetField("MyProperty1");
```

then from that field info object, you can set the value of any instance of that class.

```
field.SetValue(myinstanceofmyclass, "test");
```

See [MSDN: FieldInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.aspx) for other fun stuff you can do with reflection.

Comment: You should make distinction between a [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) and a [field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx) and use the corresponding reflection methods to manipulate them. In this case `MyProperty1` is a `property`, so calling `GetField` would likely return null.